# How to write test case using vertx for db class?

Tags: java, junit, vert.x, powermockito

Below is my written code. I want to write test cases using powermokito for db class.

I expect to write test cases for below vertx related classess using junit powermokito to cover 80% coverage. I tried different ways to mock db its not working here. How I write test case for below code? Below code include db verticle and http server verticle.

```
public class EmployeeDBVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  private JDBCPool jdbcpool;

  @Override
  public void start() throws Exception {
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.put("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee");
    jsonObject.put("driver_class", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    jsonObject.put("max_pool_size", 30);
    jsonObject.put("user", "root");
    jsonObject.put("password","root");
    jdbcpool = JDBCPool.pool(vertx,jsonObject);

    vertx.eventBus().consumer(EventBusAddresses.ADDRESS_SAVE, message -> {
    JsonObject student = (JsonObject) message.body();
    saveStudent(student)
      .onSuccess(success->{
        message.reply(success);
      }).onFailure(throwable -> {
        message.fail(HttpResponseStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.code(), "Error while saving");
      });
    });
  }

  public Future<String> saveStudent(JsonObject student){
    Promise<String> promise = Promise.promise();
    String id = student.getString("id");
    String name = student.getString("name");
    jdbcpool.preparedQuery(SQLConstants.INSERT_EMPLOYEE)
      .execute(Tuple.of(id,name))
      .onFailure(throwable -> {
        promise.fail("Failed");
      }).onSuccess(rows -> {
        if(rows.rowCount()>0){
          promise.complete("Data Saved Successfully");
        }else{
          promise.fail("Error occurred");
        }
      });
    return promise.future();
  }
}




public class EmployeeHttpVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {



  @Override
  public void start() throws Exception {
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
    router.route(HttpMethod.POST,"/save/employee").handler(this::saveStudent);
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router).listen(8090);
  }

  private void saveStudent(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    JsonObject student = routingContext.getBodyAsJson();
    vertx.eventBus().request(EventBusAddresses.ADDRESS_SAVE,student, reply->{
      if(reply.succeeded()){
        System.out.println(reply.result().body());
        routingContext.response().end((String) reply.result().body());
        callThirdParty(student);
      }else{
        routingContext.response().end(reply.cause().getMessage());
      }
    });
  }

  public void callThirdParty(JsonObject student){
    vertx.eventBus().request(EventBusAddresses.ADDRESS_SAVE,student);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise that you refactor this code.

You've embedded all your data access code inside Vertx.  You cannot test it without Vertx.  The coupling is not a good idea.

A better idea would be to start with an interface for your repository and implement it as a Plain Old Java Object (POJO), without any reference to Vertx.

You can test your POJO repository without Vertx that way.

Once it's running perfectly you can give an instance to Vertx controller and let it interact with the database through the POJO.

It's an idea called dependency injection.  Frameworks like Spring Boot can make this easy for you, but it's also possible to do without a framework.  Instantiate an instance of the repository POJO and give it to the Vertx controller in its constructor.  The repository POJO is now a private data member in the Vertx controller.

If you were to decide to switch from Vertx to an AWS lambda, your POJO repository doesn't have to change.  You can inject it into the lambda without change.